# Machine Learning (MATLAB) - Neural network is saved as 'struct' instead of 'network' in checkpoint

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I am training a neural network to learn a function. Everything is going great so far.

I have input matrix of 4x10000 and output matrix of 3x10000. I have much more data points than 10000. But not all of them can be fit at once so I have decided to feed pack of 10000-10000 data points and train same neural network on it.

There are three layers and 7 units in hidden layer.

So what I do is, I train the network with 10000 data points randomly and then again train on another random 10000 data points and so on.

So for this I store `CheckPoints` (in-built functionality of neural net toolkit). But what happens is that the `network`, which is being trained, is stored as `struct` in `CheckPoints` rather than `network` type itself. So when I load the checkpoint next time I run the program, it shows error something as below.

`Undefined function 'train' for input arguments of type 'struct'`

I am using `fitnet` network.

```
% Create a Fitting Network
hiddenLayerSize = 7;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize,'trainlm');

% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 60/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 20/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 20/100;


load('Highlights_Checkpoint.mat');
existanceOfCheckpoint = exist('checkpoint', 'var');
if existanceOfCheckpoint==0
else
net = (checkpoint.net);
end

% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,x,t,'useParallel', 'yes','showResources','yes', 'CheckpointFile','Highlights_Checkpoint.mat');
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't save the correct object to `checkpoint.net`. Where is the code that sets that field?

Comment: @Naveh Work of storing checkpoints are done inside `train` function. I don't explicitly store checkpoints.

Comment: You seem to load `checkpoint` from a file, since it is not initialized in the code you posted. If you use the `net` returned from `fitnet` instead of `net = (checkpoint.net)`, is everything okay?

Comment: Absolutely.
I pass two parameters in `train` function `CheckpointFile` and `Highlights_Checkpoint.mat`. So the function will store `network` in `mat` file in certain intervals.
I keep the `load('Highlights_Checkpoint.mat')` line commented the first time I run the program (Because there won't be any checkpoint file on first time). And I un-comment it in executions there after.

Comment: So it runs the first time, and in the second call throws the error? Because this proves my point.

Comment: Yeah it does throw the error the second time. But not because it can't find the stored `mat` file. Its because the `variable` I get from `checkpoint` is not of type `network`. I have no control over how the network is stored in checkpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Well solution to this problem was quite easy.

All I had to do was the following:

```
net = network(checkpoint.net);
```

And all was set. :D